# Should this function be static?

Tags: c++, image, inheritance, static

I just got a sample of code, which cannot be modified:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Image.h"
#include "Ppm.h"

int main() {

    Image* ob = 0x0;

    try
    {
        ob = new Ppm("lena.ppm");
        long kolor = countColors(*ob);
        std::cout << "Unikalnych kolorow: " << kolor << '\n';
    }
    catch (ImageError& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    delete ob;
    return 0;
}
```

I am confused with line

```
long kolor = countColors(*ob);
```

Two questions:
1) should this function be static?
2) should it be in class Image, or in Ppm, which inherit from the first one?

Comment: Let's assume we don't all know what are all those types. You want to try explaining it?

Comment: 1. Most likely no. 2. (very probably) No, since it lacks `blah.` or `blah->` or `blah::` before it.

Comment: the trick is that i'm not allowed to add anything to that code, so basicly i can't just add eg. range operator :/

Comment: So, what are you supposed to be writing? The function `countColors` could be a static function, but it can't be a member of `Image` or `Ppm`, because you can't call member functions that way.

Comment: yes, i know that i will have a memory leak, and yes, i know that when function will be static i won't be able to call a member function (it was just one of ideas)
It suppose to be a code which returns a number of unique colors in image, using map (for this eg. in *.ppm format)

Answer (score 1):

> I am confused with line
>
> long kolor = countColors(*ob);

You say that the code cannot be modified, so this line is already there in the code, and I assume the code is compiling/linking OK?

If it compiles OK, the function *declaration* for `countColors()` must be getting included from either from `Image.h` or `Ppm.h`, or from a header file that one of them includes. It certainly isn't coming from `iostream`.

If it's linking successfully, the object file or library containing the function *definition* for `countColors()` must be getting included in the link step.

We can only guess at the signature of this function; something like:

```
long countColors(const Ppm& portablePixmap);
```

...or maybe...

```
long countColors(const Image& image);
```

Whatever the signature is, it would not be declared with the keyword `static` (outside of a class), unless it was only used in the same file it's implemented in.

> 1) should this function be static?

The short answer is: it's unlikely that it is declared as static (see why below), but that's probably not what you're really asking about.

We know `countColors()` isn't a *class method* or *instance method*, because if it were, you'd **have** to call it like this<sup>1</sup>:

```
long kolor = SomeClass::countColors(*ob); // (class method)
```

or

```
long kolor = some_instance.countColors(*ob); // (instance method)
```

So if it's not a class or instance method, is it static? **Probably not**; here's why:

Say you've defined a function `foo` in file foo.c:

```
void foo(void) { ... }
```

...you can call it from bar.c:

```
#include "foo.h" // Tells compiler about foo()

void bar() { foo(); }  // COMPILES AND LINKS OK
```

...but if you had defined the function in foo.c using the `static` keyword:

```
static void foo(void) { ... }
```

...the linker treats it as private to foo.c, so you can't call it from bar.c or any other source file besides foo.c:

```
#include "foo.h" // Tells compiler about foo()

void bar() { foo(); }  // COMPILE OK, BUT LINKER ERROR!
```

> 2) should it be in class Image, or in Ppm, which inherit from the first one?

'should' implies that you're looking for the right place to put this method, but you also stated that this code can't be modified.

Are you trying to call this method from your own code, and you're not sure which header file to include, or how to call it?

Sorry, I could give you a better answer if I understood what it was you wanted to do.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> *It's possible to do evil things with macros in C/C++ like `#define countColors(x) SomeClass::countColors(x)`, but we'll ignore that possibility.*